# Xamarin.Forms, are there any other application types?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Are there any other way to create Android Application except Xamarin.Forms ?

There is a remark 
"The equivalent app written with Xamarin.Forms is called Todo."
at https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPortable. 
So, which application type present at this link?

Comment: `Tasky` uses `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS` *native* UI elements, `Todo` is written using `Xamarin.Forms` for cross-platform UI re-use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Xamarin Native to develop the Android Application. Here is the link to get started with the Xamarin Native with Android: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/

And you can also use the Xamarin.Forms `Portable` and `Shared` for the Android, iOS, UWP, Windows Phone 8/8.1 and Windows 8.1 application development.

Thank You.

Comment: Your statement is not correct, `Tasky` uses `Xamarin.Android` and `Xamarin.iOS` "native" UI elements, with a portable assembly for the "business logic" of the app. `Todo` is written using `Xamarin.Forms` for cross-platform UI re-use.

Comment: Ok, it is clear now. For A native application I will go to Android section at developer.xamarin.com, another way to create is Xamarin.Forms. It is looks like I can use both in one solution.

Comment: @Eldar Technical mixing native Android UI elements like an `Activity` or `Fragment` and `Xamarin.Forms` is not supported except through `Xamarin.Form`-based custom renderers, dependency services and native view creation. There are plans to allow creation UI elements from either to co-exist and inter-operate as "peers", but right now you pick to either use `Xamarin.Forms` as your main UI or skip it totally and only use "native" platform elements